# Mongo aggregation grouped by $sum?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say my collection has user names and unique commit id.

```
{"name" : "a","commit_id": "078d40cc537"},
{"name" : "b","commit_id": "078d40cc538"},
{"name" : "c","commit_id": "078d40cc539"},
{"name" : "a","commit_id": "078d40cc540"},
{"name" : "c","commit_id": "078d40cc541"},
{"name" : "c","commit_id": "078d40cc542"},
{"name" : "d","commit_id": "078d40cc543"}
```

I would like to generate an output grouped by # of commits. Any assistance will be much appreciated.

```
1 commit  = 2  #user b,d
2 commits = 1  #user a
3 commits = 1  #user c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The aggregation "pipeline" is exactly that, as you can "chain" or "pipe" stages together. To get your result you basically want two [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages in succession:

```js
db.commits.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$name",
        "commits": { "$sum": 1 }  
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$commits",
        "users": { "$push": "$_id" },
        "howMany": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": -1 } }
])
```

So the first totals per "user" and the second collects them by "count". Optionally sorted descending into this form:

```js
{ "_id" : 3, "users" : [ "c" ], "howMany": 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "users" : [ "a" ], "howMany": 1 }
{ "_id" : 1, "users" : [ "d", "b" ], "howMany": 2 }
```

There is no restriction on how many times a stage can appear ( within BSON size limiations )so you are not restricted to just having a single $group or other pipeline stage.